# Django related objects reference remove(obj, bulk=False)

Tags: django, bulk, django-related-manager

I've tried to use related manager remove() method with bulk=False but no success.Can anyone tell me what happened and where is mistake ? Thanks.
[image: In documentation for remove() is written like below]

In order to use remove(obj, bulk=False) I created models like
[image: Models to use remove(obj,bulk=False)]

Then I tried method itself in interactive shell like bellow:

1. I've created musician object
2. created album object with Foreign key to musician object but I didn't save it
3. I called related manager on musician object to remove album from relation with option bulk=False => I expected that this will call save on my album object and than remove foreign key relation but nothing happened, album wasn't saved nor relation on musician was removed. I expected the final call to album to give me <Album: First album None> and album to be saved in data base but it didn't happen.

[image: interactive shell testing remove(obj,bulk=False)]

4. The same procedure implemented on add(obj, bulk=False) yield expected results
   add(album2, bulk=False) saved my alabum2 and added reference to musician object

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect anything different from the output you received? In your first example `album` is an instance that's not been saved to the DB, it wouldn't be part of other queries?

Comment: I expected save() to be called because of bulk=False argument that called save() in add() method I tested before I tried remove() with bulk=False

Comment: But if you call `musician.album_set.all()` before remove() then nothing is returned because you haven't saved the album. If there is nothing to remove then there is nothing to save?

Comment: I didn't call musician.album_set.all() but just musician.album_set without all() part it is relating my musician to album object, check my add() case where I created album2 and didn't save it than I call musician.album_set.add(album2, bulk=False) and it saved album2 to DB and also  added  relation to the musician

Comment: musician.album_set without all() part returns relatedmanager object not QuerySet

Comment: >>> musician.album_set
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager object at 0x0000024464BB2EB8>